# Curl Not Sending

Tags: php, curl

I have this curls on my localhost and these just works fine doing its task. 
These curls are: [1] - GCM ; [2] - my own api.

However, when uploaded these files to my online server, curl [2] is not working but curl [1] is just doing fine.

// curl [1] - my own api

```
public function send($recipient, $message)
{
    // $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
//       $r = $client->post('http://link.to.api', [
// 'body' => [
// 'recipient' => $recipient,
//  'message' => $message['message']
// ] ]);
    // $response = $client->send($r);


    // $postData = 'recipient='.$recipient.
                // '&message='.$message['message'];


// shell_exec('curl -i -X POST "http://link.to.api" -d "'. $postData.'"');


    $url = 'http://link.to.api';

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('recipient'=>'123123', 'message'=>'assss'));  

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

}
```

// curl [2] - GCM

```
public function send($reg_ids, $message)
{
    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $GOOGLE_API_KEY = '11111111111111111111111111111111';


    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $reg_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

As you can see, I have tried different options for send my curl[2].
Any tips and help?

My website that do these things and my [link.to.api] are stored in the same server.

Comment: *is not working* is hardly a good description of the problem.

Comment: well, as I stated, these functions work fine in my localhost but not in online server.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('recipient'=>'123123', 'message'=>'assss'));
```

I just change the above code to this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

where $postData is:

```
$postData = 'recipient='.$recipient.'&message='.$message['message']
```

Alas!